# How to update text in text view during program execution?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have in MainActivity text view (textViewLog). In this text view i will print all programm results during programm execution. I tried handlers, threads, async tasks... but nothing is working properly.

Or all of the text printed at the end of the program; 
Or text printed in the course of the program (using Handler), but the program does not work until the end.

Does anyone have any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Show some code of what you are trying to do exactly to give everyone a better idea of what you are trying to do.

Comment: If you mean how to change the text from another thread than the UI thread, look at `runOnUiThread()`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to change text at certain points in the program, you can programatically set new text during execution to your TextView with `textViewLog.setText(yourString);`

Comment: yeah, I can make textViewLog.setText(myString), but this result I see at the end of the program, because in one main thread, all updates on Activity screen will be updated after onCreate() method execution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `textView.setText("ur value")` whenever you want to update it. If I am have not understood you, then could I see your code....

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        textViewLog = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewLog);

        LoadSetupPlist();
        LoadMenuPlist();

        getConnectionToDataBase();
        startApp();
    }
}
```

everything happens in this 4 functions: 
        LoadSetupPlist();
        LoadMenuPlist();
        getConnectionToDataBase();
        startApp();

At the beginning I have this -

[image]

Then when i push "Yes" - my application downloads xml-file from web service, then updates database with data from xml file. At that time i will print on screen results...

If I print result so

```
public void printOnScreen() {
    MainActivity.textViewLog.setTextSize(12);
    MainActivity.textViewLog.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    MainActivity.textViewLog.setTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    MainActivity.textViewLog.setText(MainActivity.textViewLog.getText() +       
                                     System.getProperty("line.separator") + 
                                     "-> sending_done1");
}
```

then I become all results on screen, but when database updating finished 
(sorry for yellow color) -

[image: image2]

I will print this results, during database updating